# I'm having trouble displaying a horizontal bar chart using a result tree fragment

Tags: xml, xslt, fragment

I'm new to XSL, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. The page is supposed to show election results, with a horizontal bar chart corresponding to the percentage of votes received for each candidate. I'm having trouble displaying a horizontal bar chart using a result tree fragment.

I've tried doing my research, but I'm stuck. Can someone please help? Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Tr…
<xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" />

<xsl:variable name="redcell">
<td class="red"> </td>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="bluecell">
<td class="blue"> </td>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="greencell">
<td class="green"> </td>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
<title>Election Night Results</title>
<link href="polls.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="intro">
<p><img src="logo.jpg" alt="Election Day Results" /></p>
<a href="#">Election Home Page</a>
<a href="#">President</a>
<a href="#">Senate Races</a>
<a href="#">Congressional Races</a>
<a href="#">State Senate</a>
<a href="#">State House</a>
<a href="#">Local Races</a>
<a href="#">Judicial</a>
<a href="#">Referendums</a>
</div>

<div id="results">
<h1>Congressional Races</h1>
<xsl:apply-templates select="polls/race" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="candidate">
<xsl:variable name="percent" select="votes div sum(..//votes)" />
<tr>
<td class="name"><xsl:value-of select="name" /> (<xsl:value-of select="party" />)</td>
<td class="num"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(votes, '#,##0')" /> (<xsl:value-of select="format-number($percent, '#0%')" />)</td>
<xsl:apply-templates select="showBar">
<xsl:with-param name="cells" select="$percent * 100" />
<xsl:with-param name="partyType" select="party" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
</tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="race">
<h2><xsl:value-of select="title" /></h2>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
<tr><th>Candidate</th><th class="num">Votes</th></tr>
<xsl:apply-templates select="candidate" />
</table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="showBar">
<xsl:param name="cells" select="0" />
<xsl:param name="partyType" />

<xsl:if test="$cells > 0">

<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$partyType='R'">
<xsl:copy-of select="$redcell" />
</xsl:when>

<xsl:when test="$partyType='D'">
<xsl:copy-of select="$bluecell" />
</xsl:when>

<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:copy-of select="$greencell" />
</xsl:otherwise>

</xsl:choose>

<xsl:call-template name="showBar">
<xsl:with-param name="cells" select="$cells - 1" />
<xsl:with-param name="partyType" select="party" />
</xsl:call-template>

</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Some example input XML and desired out XML would make it easier to help you

Comment: It would also help to know, if you're having trouble, what the nature of your trouble is. Just showing us some code and saying it doesn't work isn't enough to go on (there's nothing in the code that screams out as being obviously wrong).

Comment: I'm supposed to have a series of bars for each candidate. That's the code in the redcell/bluecell/greencell fragments. For some reason, those bars aren't showing up at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="showBar">
```

You don't want to apply templates to `showBar` elements. You want to call the named template "showBar". Use this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="showBar">
```

And change the closing tag as well.

By the way, your spaces are going to get collapsed in those td elements. You can use xsl:text to prevent that, e.g.

```
<xsl:text>
```